# Retrive data from form submission and display it on a page

Tags: asp.net, forms

I would like to put a form on my page. There will be an input box and a submit button. When the user enter a specific id then i will take that id put it in a url and display the result from that url.

Let say user enter this: 12345678.

Then i want to take that id display the result from

http://foo.com/servlet/AccessModule?id=12345678&doc_type=pdf&sort1=capturedate&response=A on my page using asp.net technologies.

I already tried a couple of things but couldnt figure this out.

Can you please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it could work. This needs some polishing but you should be able to bring it to completion yourself.

Copy this into .aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" /><br /><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult" Text=""></asp:Label>

    </div>
</form>
```

And this into code behind (I’m assuming you’re using C#)

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    lblResult.Text = 
wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://foo.com/servlet/AccessModule?id={0}&doc_type=pdf&sort1=capturedate&response=A", txtInput.Text));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="www.foo.com/search" method="get">
  ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Jimmy, i edited my question. What if my query is like this: http://foo.com:29005/servlet/AccessModule?id=12345678&doc_type=pdf&sort1=capturedate&response=A

Comment: use hidden fileds in the form to send the other values.

e.g. <input type="hidden" name="doc_type" value="pdf">

Answer (score 1):

When you send an http request it reaches the server on port 8080. You can not specify the port that you are going to use.
To pass parameters in URL you have to use this

```
repsonse.redirect("AccessModule.aspx?id=12345678&doc_type=pdf&sort1=capturedate&response=A");
```

Comment: Port is not the issue. I wrote that as an example. Now i removed that part.

Comment: so this my example would work then, just make sure to give it the right path to the aspx file based on your current page location in the site. If my answer helped you would you please mark it as answer.

Comment: first of all what I have written is server side code. so you have to add asp:button not html input of type button. Then open the designer of the page. double click on the button. A click button handler function will be generated for you. It is where you can process your data and send the user to another page.  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          repsonse.redirect("AccessModule.aspx?id=12345678&doc_type=pdf&sort1=capturedate&response=A");
        }

Comment: Thanks but repsonse.redirect("AccessModule.aspx?id=12345678&doc_type=pdf&sort1=capturedate&‌​response=A"); id will always get the data from form submission. so shouldnt it to be a variable or something? if i just write id=12345678 it will only show the result for this specific id.

Comment: Yes it should be available. In you website design you should for example show all documents in one page with small brief about each one. Then when the user click on a document he will be redirected to a page with full details about this document. So in the first page you should know every document ID and embed it in the code like this: repsonse.redirect("AccessModule.aspx?id=" + MyDocument.ID + );